# How to visualize tile-map Kibana elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm not sure why my data points aren't visualized in the tile-map. I'm dynamically adding the data points through the elasticsearch python client (https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/). The visualization keeps returning 
[image]
Furthermore, here is initial mapping of the geo_point.

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "geo": {
            "properties": {
                "location": {
                    "type": "geo_point",
                    "geohash": true,
                    "geohash_prefix": true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your mapping is not set up correctly, Kibana doesn't let you select the geohash aggregation in the config panel on the left. This rather seems to be a problem with the indexed data.

What does the timestamp in your mapping look like? Do you have such recent data that your time selection should return some results for the last 15 minutes? Please check the selection at the top right corner...

Comment: the data is time-series data. Please see the additional image

Comment: Can you please expand one of the rows with some non-empty coordinates? Looks like the mapping is on `geo.location` but the values are under `geo.coord`?

Comment: those are interchangeable, I have edited the question for consistency. Thanks